# How to generate a route using a string type parameter

Tags: laravel, routes

In my controller method, a line is created

```
public function createImg(Request $request, $id)
{
    $url = url()->previous();
    $start = env('APP_URL');
    $path = explode($start , $url)[1];

some code

    return view('img', ['path'=>$path, 'param'=>$param]);
}
```

I need to generate a route

```
Route::get('/{path}/img/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ImgController@createImg')
```

Is it possible to pass a string to a route? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it as you already did.

You add another parameters to your method, in proper order.

In other words, if your route looks as such:

`'/{path}/img/{id}'`

Then your function in the controller should look like this:

`public function createImg(Request $request, $path, $id)`

---

Also point of note, you don't have to pass entire path as such:

`'App\Http\Controllers\ImgController@createImg'`

It's sufficient to just pass: `'ImgController@createImg'`.

Comment: I honestly did not know that order matters. Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to say, is it possible to pass a string from a route to a controller?  If so, then yes, this is perfectly valid.

```php
Route::get('/{path}/img/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ImgController@createImg');
```

You would just add the parameter to the controller.

```php
public function createImg(Request $request, $path, $id)
```